# Comparar elementos de un arreglo Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for, bucles, javascript-objeto

tengo un problema al hacer una pequeña validación que consiste en comparar un arreglo de tipo String con una propiedad de un objeto.

Si todos los elementos del arreglo headers coinciden con los valores de la propiedad uztfilecolumn_NOMBRE, la variable correcto pasa hacer true, si cualquiera de los elementos de headers no coinciden la variable correcto valdrá false.

Pero el problema es que el 3er elemento del arreglo headers es: asdsad y el valor de la propiedad del objeto es: "Valor env."
por lo cual el valor de la variable correcto debería ser "false",

pero me da true, alguien me podria ayudar en que estoy haciendo o me recomiendan otra forma de hacer la validación

```js
 let correcto = Boolean;
 let headers = ["Orden", "Contrapartida", "Nombre", "asdsad", 
                "No. referencia", "Forma pago","Fecha de Depósito"];
       
 let val = [
       {
          "uztfilecolumn_ID" : 1,
          "uztfilecolumn_NOMBRE": "Orden"
      },
       {
          "uztfilecolumn_ID": 2,
          "uztfilecolumn_NOMBRE": "Contrapartida"
      },
      {
          "uztfilecolumn_ID": 3,
          "uztfilecolumn_NOMBRE": "Nombre"
      },
      {
          "uztfilecolumn_ID": 4,
          "uztfilecolumn_NOMBRE": "Valor env."
      },
      {
          "uztfilecolumn_ID": 5,
          "uztfilecolumn_NOMBRE": "No. referencia"
      },
      {
          "uztfilecolumn_ID": 6,
          "uztfilecolumn_NOMBRE": "Forma pago"
      },
       {
          "uztfilecolumn_ID": 7,
          "uztfilecolumn_NOMBRE": "Fecha de Depósito"
      }
            ]
            
           
            for (var u = 0; u < headers.length; u++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < val.length; j++) {
                    if (headers[u] === val[j].uztfilecolumn_NOMBRE) {
                    console.log("validacion: ",headers[u] + " = " + val[j].uztfilecolumn_NOMBRE + " = ", );
                    correcto = true;
                    }else{
                        correcto= false;
                    }
                }
            }
            console.log("validacion es: ", correcto);
```

En el console.log final el valor del 3er elemento pasa a ser "Valor env." en vez de asdsad que es su verdadero valor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pasa que en tu ciclo estas reevaluando la variable `correcto` por cada iteración, es por esto que aunque `correcto` se le ponga el valor `false` en la tercera iteración, las siguientes iteraciones van a sobreescribirla y así hasta el final, dejando entonces `correcto` con el valor correspondiente a la última iteración, es decir `true`.

Acá rehice tu código pero con una condición de salida para hacer más eficiente el código y disminuir las comparaciones, además validé si las listas tienen largos distintos, sino el algoritmo fallaría

Acá el código:

```js
    let headers = ["Orden", "Contrapartida", "Nombre", "asdsad", 
                    "No. referencia", "Forma pago","Fecha de Depósito"];
           
    let val = [
           {
              "uztfilecolumn_ID" : 1,
              "uztfilecolumn_NOMBRE": "Orden"
          },
           {
              "uztfilecolumn_ID": 2,
              "uztfilecolumn_NOMBRE": "Contrapartida"
          },
          {
              "uztfilecolumn_ID": 3,
              "uztfilecolumn_NOMBRE": "Nombre"
          },
          {
              "uztfilecolumn_ID": 4,
              "uztfilecolumn_NOMBRE": "Valor env."
          },
          {
              "uztfilecolumn_ID": 5,
              "uztfilecolumn_NOMBRE": "No. referencia"
          },
          {
              "uztfilecolumn_ID": 6,
              "uztfilecolumn_NOMBRE": "Forma pago"
          },
           {
              "uztfilecolumn_ID": 7,
              "uztfilecolumn_NOMBRE": "Fecha de Depósito"
          }
    ]
    let correcto = true //es válido hasta que se demuestre lo contrario
    if(val.length === headers.length){
        for (var u = 0; u < headers.length; u++) { 
            if (headers[u] !== val[u].uztfilecolumn_NOMBRE) {
                    correcto = false; //se demuestra lo contrario
                    break; // se termina el ciclo pues ya no es válido
            }
        }
    } else {
        correcto = false //las listas tienen largos distintos, por lotanto, no es válido
    }
    console.log("validacion es: ", correcto);
```

Comment: Precisamente iba a responder algo así, pero me ganaste y, aparte, lo explicaste muy bien. +1

Comment: muchas gracias, ya pude corregir el error